# Go template ranging over struct of structs

Tags: templates, go, struct

I'm attempting to range over a list of a struct consisting of 2 structs inside of it.  I have no problem filling the data correctly in the struct, the problem is when I try to render it into the HTML.  I can't get anything to display.

This is my first go web project and I'm working on a website to sell cars for a small business.  My Database is designed as a 1..M of Cars to Pics.  So on the main car page.  I want to just load 1 pic with the details of the car.  I tried using a map for this but I ran into an issue when I wanted to print out just 1 picture to go with the correct car details on the common ID.  So I figured using a third struct that I pull out one pic for each ID would work.

```
type Car struct {
    Id int
    Year, Make, Model, Price string
}

type Pics struct {
    Id int
    Path string
}


type CarDetail struct {
    Cars Car
    Pic Pics
}

func cars(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
  //loads all the cars in the database
  cars := loadCars()
  carDetails := make([]CarDetail,0)
  carIds := make([]int,len(cars))
  for i := 0; i < len(cars); i++{
    //gets all the car IDs in the db
    carIds[i] = getCarID(cars[i]) 
    photoPath := loadSinglePhoto(carIds[i]) //now have the single photo
    n := CarDetail{Cars:cars[i],Pic:photoPath}
    carDetails = append(carDetails, n)
}

fmt.Println(carDetails) //getting car details the way I want
tpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "cars", &carDetails)
}
```

The print statement right before I pass in the struct gives me the information the way I intended.

[{{20 2009 Honda Accord 5000} {20 public/pics/questionMark.jpg}} {{21 2009 Acura TLX 14000} {21 public/pics/kia.png}} {{22 2015 Kia Sportage 34000} {22 public/pics/kia.png}}]

Now when I try to render it in the html

```
{{range .}}
  <h3>{{.Cars.Make}} - {{.Cars.Model}} - {{.Cars.Year}}</h3>
  <img src="{{.Pic.Path}}" id="{{.Pic.Id}}">
{{end}}
```

Feel free to be critical of my code or suggest another way.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: *Always* check `error` returned by `ExecuteTemplate`. The `"cars"` is supposed to be template name not variable name. Instead of `ExecuteTemplate`, you can use `tpl.Execute(w, &carsDetail)`.

Answer (score 1):

Some remarks on a general level:

- Your naming is a bit misleading: Pics holds only a single picture, not many (not an array or map); same applies to CarDetail.Cars
- Not knowing which database you are using I would recommend to build a query returning both cars and (primary) picture, as looking the pics up by every single car will not perform well
- I would recommend storing the templates as files in a sub-folder with specific extensions (e.g. "cars.gohtml") and then use template.ParseGlob("templates/*.gohtml")

Apart from that it should work, see a slightly refactored working example here:
https://play.golang.org/p/CPnad9FxaB

So what exactly is going wrong in your own code?

Comment: Thank you for the remarks.  Essentially when I load the page, I'm not seeing any data in the cars.html page.  I already have a folder for templates.  The single query is a great point. Would you recommend adding a field for 'primary' just to pull that 1 pic?  

The problem I'm having is it won't render anything to the page.  It works if I try a single one, but ranging over the list of CarDetails is not rendering anything on the html page

Comment: What's strange is that it works fine when I pass in a list of 'CarDetail', but when I try pulling it from the database, it does not work.  I know the information is there because it prints out fine right before I execute the template.  i.e. You're example provided works fine.  But for my example up top nothing renders.  No errors are returned, and the page loads, just no data from server side.

Comment: Possibly go templating does not observe the HTML comments <!-- -->, so maybe your "commented out HTML" received your data :) Just try again with your comments and inspect the source code of your rendered page in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

So I found the culprit.  Strangely enough some commented out HTML code from earlier was causing the template not to be rendered.  I'm not sure why.

```
<!--

<h1>Your Pictures:</h1>
{{range .Pics}}
<img class="insertedPics" src="{{.Path}}" alt="pic" id="{{.Id}}" 
height="500px" width="500px">
{{end}}

{{range .Cars}}
<h3>{{.Make}} - {{.Model}} - {{.Year}} </h3>
{{end}}

<img src="{{.Pic.Path}}" alt="car pic" id="{{.Car.Id}}" height="600px" width="600px">

-->        <-- Once I removed this, everything worked fine.

{{range .}}
<h3>{{.C.Make}} - {{.C.Model}}</h3>
<img src="{{.P.Path}}" alt="some pic" height="500px" width="500px" 
style="">
{{end}}
```

Thank you for the help and suggestions!